# JSON-data to UITableView is still empty

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, ios7

I have loaded JSON data from my website and added it to a `UITableView` but the Table is still empty.. The app doesn't crash, so I have really no idea whats wrong maybe someone of you could help me. I will give you the code below and also the connection of the FilesOwner.

Thanks in advance

My JSON Data file:

```
[
{ name: "XYZ", details: "XYZ"},
{ name: "XYZ", details: "XYZ"}
]
```

ViewController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableData;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *myObject;
    NSDictionary *data;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *details;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    name = @"name";
    details = @"details";

    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/JSON/index.php"];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *name_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *details_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"details"];

        data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      name_data,name,
                      details_data,details,
                nil];
        [myObject addObject:data];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return myObject.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSMutableString *title;
    //text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:title]];
    title = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
            [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:name]];

    NSMutableString *second;
    second = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              [tmpDict objectForKey:details]];


    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= second;


    return cell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Main.storyboard:

Reuse Identifier of the Prototypecell is "Item".

`dataSource` is connected to ViewController
`delegate`   is connected to ViewController
`tableData`  is connected to ViewController

This is all I have done so...
Much thanks :)

Comment: At the end of your parsing, try a `reloadData` on your TableView

Comment: I added `[tableView reloadData];` in the end of the `UITableViewCell` Method, nothing happens..

Comment: why don't you use `jsonObjects` directly and forgo `myObject` since `myObject` is, technically, no different than `jsonObjects`. plus... why do you use `objectForKeyedSubscript`, i'd suggest using `objectForKey` instead? (_not sure but these suggestions might not really help you with the core issue but would be an improvement atleast_)

Comment: also... does `jsonSource` have valid contents? set a breakpoint at the end of `-viewDidLoad` and check if `jsonSource` and `myObject` look like how you'd expect them to look like

Comment: At the end of the `ViewDidLoad` `myObject` has 0 Objects in it... so there must be a parse failure, if i'm right? I also thought before that objective-c maybe couldn't read a php file correctly, but I didn't found a solution to name it like an commercial API..

Comment: if you think it's a parse failure then check the contents of the `jsonObjects` variable (_does it read as an array or is it nil... etc_)

Comment: and say, i hit this `http://example.com/JSON/index.php` via the browser, what should i expect? a json? (_ain't that wrong terminology?_) but anyways... if this `index.php` is to send a `json` object then you can't simply get away with `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`. You need to do `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` and the sorts. I guess your root problem lies here.

Comment: ok.. thanks so far, i will check the submition of the JSON.. The link i have posted is not the link to my website, but what you get is exactly the schematic of the example i have posted, there is no difference..

Comment: Are Json objects coming out of NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: ok, then you have an invalid json. you're missing the quotes. it should be `[{"name":"XYZ","details":"XYZ"},{"name":"XYZ","details":"XYZ"}]` (_observe the quotes for **name** and **details** keys that were previously missing_... use an online tool like [JSONEditorOnline](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to check the validity of a json file_)

Comment: JSONEditorOnline helped me to solve it! The code below from @meda is correctly working! It's solved now and thanks to every one who helped me :)

Comment: great, i'll post an answer as well since there are other tiny issues with your code (_sure to surface later_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing quotes for the key name in your json response.

```
[
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "details": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "details": "XYZ"
  }
]
```

Also, for improvement sake, use `jsonObjects` directly (*currently you are reading `jsonObjects` and making `myObject` which is no different than `jsonObjects` itself*)

And... since you're using a **prototype cell**, your current way of doing things in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is wrong.
**i.e:** Currently, you have an `if (cell == nil)` block which... is useless (*with prototype cells*) and you will end up seeing only `cell.textLabel.text`.

### Proper way:

1. Go to storyboard
2. Select the protoype cell

   - (*via Interface Builder on the right*) Change it's style from `custom` to `subtitle`

### Finally...

Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/JSON/index.php"];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //declare NSArray *jsonObjects; in the .h
    jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource 
                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                    error:nil];
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //useless when using a prototype cell
    //if (cell == nil) {
    //    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
    //                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //}

    //fyi: old style
    //NSString *strName = [[jsonObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    //NSString *strDetails = [[jsonObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"details"];

    //new style (but doesn't matter which one you adopt)
    NSString *strName = jsonObjects[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    NSString *strDetails = jsonObjects[indexPath.row][@"details"];

    [cell.textLabel setText:strName];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:strDetails];

    return cell;
}
```

---

**FYI:** It was mainly the json that was invalid.
Your original code would have worked had your json been in the right format but surely the prototype cell would have needed to be fixed up properly.

Answer (score 1):

**viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/JSON/index.php"];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //store the JSON into an array
    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    myObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource 
                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**numberOfSectionsInTableView**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return myObject.count;
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary * obj = myObject[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = obj[@"name"] ;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= obj[@"details"] ;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i tested your solution, the table is still empty, but thanks for your idea

Comment: ok just come back to work, i'm now using a different json php script, and its working! I haven't tested it yet if its working directly with my code but your code is working. So I have to spell a very great THANKS :) you did a great Job.

Comment: @Criska nice , Good luck with your app `;-)`

Comment: @meda : Criska's issue was an invalid json which had been pointed out in the question comments. What you suggested was just a more efficient way of doing things but would not have solved his problem because `myObject` would have remained `nil` until the json was fixed (_...all of which was pointed out in the comments_) I was just waiting to be sure about the OP's core issue before posting an answer.